# Is killing form a norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

This referees to the link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KillingForm.html , where it clearly states that killing form is an inner product. Further it is also known that inner product induces a norm. So does killing form induces a norm?

EDIT (After viewing some answers):  Some excellent answers proved that killing form cannot be norm in general. At least is there a condition under such the killing form can be a norm?

Comment: Take for example, say, the Heisenberg Lie algebra and compute its Killing form. The you will see the problem, even over the real numbers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, I see the problem through reals only.

Comment: Yes, over the reals, the Killing form of the Heisenberg Lie algebra is identically zero. Not really useful for an inner product.

Comment: Maybe some people as in the given Mathworld link consider that an inner product is just a quadratic form. Or possibly assumed non-degenerate. For a finite-dimensional real Lie algebra $g$, the Killing form is (1) non-degenerate iff $g$ is semisimple (2) definite-positive if and only if $g=0$ (2) definite-negative if and only if $g$ is "compact", which for $g$ semisimple means that for every $x\in g$, $ad(x)$ has only eigenvalues in $i\mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the killing form is not necessarily an inner product. If the killing form is degenerate, then it is not an inner product. Also, Lie algebras can be over any field while inner products map to real of complex numbers

Answer (score 3):

The killing for is non degenerated if and only if the Lie algebra is semi-simple. It is an inner product if the Lie algebra is compact and semi-simple in this case it is negative definite.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Lie_algebra